# How to properly create defaults with apollo-link-state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, browser-cache, apollo

I'm currently migrating an application I developed from redux to apollo. I'm following [this](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-link-state/tree/master/examples/todo) example trying to implement `apollo-link-state` and `apollo-cache-inmemory` but I'm struggling to understand how their framework works. It would be great if someone could answer some questions, so here we go:

Use Case: Store modals information (basically wether it's open or not) in my cache memory

Here is my code:

```
// apollos.js
import { ApolloClient } from 'apollo-client';
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory';
import { withClientState } from 'apollo-link-state';
import { HttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http';
import { ApolloLink } from 'apollo-link';

import { modalStateQuery } from "./common/queries/modal.query";

const httpLinkOptions = {
    uri: 'http://localhost:8080/graphql',
};
const httpLink = new HttpLink(httpLinkOptions);

const cache = new InMemoryCache({
    dataIdFromObject: o => o.id
});

const typeDefs = `
    type Modal {
        id: ID!
        open: Boolean!
    }

    type Query {
        modal(id: ID!): Modal
        modals: [Modal]
    }
`;

const defaults = {
    modals: [
        {
            __typename: "Modal",
            id: "login",
            open: false
        },
        {
            __typename: "Modal",
            id: "signup",
            open: false
        }
    ]
};

const resolvers = {
    Query: {
        modal: (_, { id }, { cache }) => {
            console.log("get modal");
            try {
                const data = cache.readQuery({ query: modalStateQuery.getOne, variables: { id } });
                console.log("data", data);
            } catch (e) {
                console.log("error", e);
            }

            return null;
        },
        modals: (_, { }, { cache }) => {
            console.log("Modal List Resolver"); // this is never logged
        }
    }
}

const stateLink = withClientState({
    cache,
    resolvers,
    defaults,
    typeDefs
});

const link = ApolloLink.from([stateLink, httpLink]);

const client = new ApolloClient({
    link,
    cache,
    dataIdFromObject: o => o.id
});

export default client;
```

-

```
// modal.query.js
import gql from "graphql-tag";

export const modalStateQuery = {
    getOne: gql`
        query ModalState($id: String!) {
            modal(id: $id) @client {
                id
                open    
            }
        }`,
    getAll: gql`
        query {
            modals @client {
                id
                open
            }
        }
    `
};
```

-

```
// modal.js
// ...
// fetching both for test purposes
export default compose(
    graphql(modalStateQuery.getOne, { name: "modal" }),
    graphql(modalStateQuery.getAll, { name: "allModals" })
)(Modal);
```

Ok, now the questions:

The number one problem I'm having is with the `modal($id: id)` query. When I execute `modalStateQuery.getAll` the `modals` resolver is never called, but I still get the list I defined in `defaults` in my component. But when I execute `modalStateQuery.getOne` I always get the same error:

```
error Error: Can't find field modal({"id":"login"}) on object (ROOT_QUERY) {
  "modals": [
    {
      "type": "id",
      "generated": false,
      "id": "login",
      "typename": "Modal"
    },
    {
      "type": "id",
      "generated": false,
      "id": "signup",
      "typename": "Modal"
    }
  ]
}.
    at readStoreResolver (readFromStore.js:71)
    at executeField (graphql.js:90)
    at graphql.js:46
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at executeSelectionSet (graphql.js:40)
    at graphql (graphql.js:35)
    at diffQueryAgainstStore (readFromStore.js:124)
    at readQueryFromStore (readFromStore.js:37)
    at InMemoryCache../node_modules/apollo-cache-inmemory/lib/inMemoryCache.js.InMemoryCache.read (inMemoryCache.js:84)
    at InMemoryCache../node_modules/apollo-cache-inmemory/lib/inMemoryCache.js.InMemoryCache.readQuery (inMemoryCache.js:181)
```

What is this array it is showing to me? Why isn't there all the props I defined in `defaults` (like `open: false`)? Could it be something wrong with the way I create my `defaults`?

In the `apollo-cache-inmemory` [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/apollo-cache-inmemory) it doesn't define any resolvers, it just says that you should query your data just like you are doing it in the backend, passing the variables.

Also, why does `modalStateQuery.getAll` works even though the resolver is never called? What if I do want that resolver to be called (Maybe I want to check my backend first to check permissions or smth)?

Another curious behavior I noticed: When executing the `modal` resolver, the `id` variable is always correct, even though I didn't explicitly pass it as variable in my component, but the `Modal.js` component does have an `id` props that I pass to it:

```
return <Modal id="login"><LoginForm /></Modal>;
```

It makes me believe that apollo already recognizes that the `Modal.js` is being called with an `id` prop and automatically passes it to the query as a variable. Is that correct? It does it for any variable?

Thanks!